# Importing a python module from the python script from drive in colab

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

I am currently working on a project on Machine Learning on Google Colab which uses Tensorflow API. I created a folder and uploaded it on google drive to run on google Colab.
I successfully mounted the google drive and can run the script,
But when I try importing another module from the script present in the same folder, it throws an error

```
    from . import inference
    ImportError: cannot import name 'inference'
```

I tried finding out a solution for this but found results stating how to import a module directly to the colab notebook.

Please tell me what I am missing here.

Edit:
The folder structure is

```
-nmt
  -nmt.py
  -train.py
  -inference.py
  -utils
    -evaluation.py
```

and so on.
And I am running the python file from the nmt folder. I am getting relative import errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First, upload the `.py` file and then save it locally. Then you may use it as you like it.

```
from google.colab import files
src = list(files.upload().values())[0]
open('library_you_want_to_use.py','wb').write(src)
import library_you_want_to_use
```